# Java Spring boot storing a file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, backend

I am trying to store a file from user, using Java Spring boot and make a preview immediately after image upload. But now I get a 404 error on the console and when I refresh the page, the image shows up! 
I tried to solve the problem by adding sleep or delay in the thread. Did not work. Here is some part of controller and service file:

```
    public Resource getIllustrationAsResource(long id) throws MalformedURLException {
        return new FileUrlResource(uploadLocation + id + ILLUSTRATION_FILE_ENDING);
    }

    public PostResult addIllustration(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        Illustration illustration = getIllustrationMetadata(file);
        long id = repo.insertIllustration(illustration);
        storeFile(file, id);
        return new PostResult(id);
    }

    private void storeFile(MultipartFile file, long id) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(uploadLocation + id + ILLUSTRATION_FILE_ENDING);
        System.out.println("storeFile path: " + path);
        File uploadFile = new File(uploadLocation);
        uploadFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
            Files.copy(inputStream, path);
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/illustrations/{id}/image")
public ResponseEntity < Resource > getImageContent(@PathVariable("id") long id)
throws MalformedURLException {
    Illustration illustrationInfo = service.getOneIllustration(id);
    Resource body = service.getIllustrationAsResource(id);

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(illustrationInfo.getMime()));
    return new ResponseEntity < > (body, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PostMapping("/illustrations")
public PostResult postOneIllustration(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile image)
throws IOException {
    ProjectId project = projectService.getCurrentProject();
    if (project == null) {
        throw new EntityMissingException();
    }
    if (!authorizationService.loggedInUserCanCreateObjectsInProject(project)) {
        throw new EntityMissingException();
    }
    return service.addIllustration(image);
}
```

Frontend:

```
postFile: async function(data) {
   //console.log("here")
   try {
     let fetchPromise = catchReject(
       fetch(`${window.contextPath}/illustrations`, {
         method: 'POST',
         body: data
       })
     )
     const response = await fetchPromise
     validateHttpOkStatus(response)
     return response.json()
   } catch (e) {
     console.log('in postFile')
     console.log(e)
     // store.dispatch(addGlobalError(e))
     throw e
   }
 },
```

Comment: How you are invoking `/illustrations` and `/illustrations/{id}/image` from client side? if you are using ajax call the image may not have uploaded the time you are trying to get. you may have to synchronize these two calls.

Comment: Hi Kapil, I am using async function as updated in question

Comment: The code seems correct, but, by making an asynchronous call to read the file, there is a possibility that the file is not yet consolidated in the file system.
I would make sure of that by returning a boolean, using the Files.exists method.